# Where I define http://localhost:8080/"homepage"

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am working with eclipse and I run my project with Apache Tomcat.

I have the following files:

**1. applicationContext.xml**

**2. dispatcher-Servlet.xml**

**3. web.xml**

**4. pom.xml**

I also have the following packages

**controller, dao, impl, model.**

I would like my homepage to be "MyHomePage". So when I run the project my first url will be : http://localhost:8080/MyHomePage.

In which of the above files/packages I have to define this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant `http://localhost:8080/MyHomePage.html`

then you specify the home page in `web.xml` like this

```
<web-app>
 ....
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>MyHomePage.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

You will also need to place an html file by the name `MyHomePage.html` at the root folder of the web site, which, in the case of Tomcat, is WebContent:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 `-- MyHomePage.html
```